# USA Visa stamping after overstaying for minors

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I am Indian citizen.I have L1-A visa, my wife and two daughters have L2-A dependent visa. 
We had approved petition expiring in February 2019, We went to India in July 2018 and got stamping done for myself and daughters.

Stamping was approved and valid till February 2019, however my daughters passport were expiring in September 2018 hence at the port of entry they received I-94 valid till September 2018 only.

I completely missed to file I-94 extension for my daughters and filed same in January 2019.

In January 2019, filed Petition and I-94 extension for all of us. First received RFE asking for more documents supporting my managerial activities and role.
Next received Notice Of Intent To Deny and asking for more documents supporting my managerial activities and role.
On 19th April 2019, petition approved after responding to NOID and received I-797B approval but without extended I-94 attached to it.

Did not receive any approvals / I-797 for my wife and daughters.

I-94 of myself and my wife expired in February 2019 and received petition approval in April 2019 without extended I-94.
Does this mean I am out of status from February 2019 ? I left the country and going for visa stamping. WHat are the chances of getting visa ?

My daughters (Age : 8 & 14) have been out of status for more than 6 months, do they fall under 3 & 10 year bar being monor ? Minor gets exception as pe the law ?

212(a)(9)(B) ALIENS UNLAWFULLY PRESENT (iii) Exceptions (I) Minors.-No period of time in which an alien is under 18 years of age shall be taken into account in determining the period of unlawful presence in the United States.

what are the chances for their visa approval ? Will there be any issues for them if in future as adult they want to visit United States ?

Comment: Hi Rahul, this is on the wrong site.  But you of course, absolutely, NEED A TOP IMMIGRATION ATTORNEY.  It's inconceivable you could get the right advice for this situation on the net.  (Indeed, surely the corporation you work for has legal support for this??)